# Need to filter SQL database data by time interval (1 sec, 1Min, 10 Min,1Hour, 2Hour)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures

I want filter SQL database data by time interval (1 sec, 1Min, 10 Min,1Hour, 2Hour)
I want to fetch data from "ProDataTable" by in between Start Date and End Date with Interval of (1 Sec, 1Min, 10 Min, 1 Hour , 2 hour)

[image: ProDataTable]
for Fetching data from Database i am using following query.

`Select * 
from ProDataTable
Where Date_Time between '2017-11-17 19:05' AND '2017-11-21 19:23'`

So kindly let me know how i can filter out data by time interval (1 sec, 1Min, 10 Min,1Hour, 2Hour).

I want result as follows 
Exa : for 1 Min
[image: for 1 Min]

Exa : for 1 1hour

[image: for 1 1hour]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "filter out" do you just want to aggregate your data to the nearest second, minute, hour or are you looking for specific records that happen at a precise moment?

Comment: Hello Brownstone,I group data for ( 1hour interval, 1 sec interval and 1 min interval as mention in result picture.

Comment: Do you want the data in the non-timestamp columns aggregated? Average, max, etc.? All of the data in your example images is identical, so it's hard to know how you want this presented.

Comment: Hello Dan ,Yes, I want data as like show in example images . I don't want  Average, max, etc.

Comment: So, you want the first entry in your date range; then, from there, you want the record with the timestamp closest to (start date + interval), repeat until (current row date + interval) falls outside the date range? From the sample shown, you have data for the smallest interval listed - what if there's a period where that's not the case (for instance, say there's no data for 18-11-2017 22:00 - 23:00).

Comment: Atleast you should have given data in textual form.now how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, you wish to group the data by date and time based on a specified degree of granularity. There is a good article by Steve Stedman which demonstrates [how to round a date in T-SQL](http://stevestedman.com/2012/10/tsql-rounding-datetime-to-nearest-seconds/).

You can use the technique that he pointed out to group by the date to a specific granularity. Based upon your comments you say that you do not wish to apply any aggregation technique to the non-date/time data - this will give you a lot of duplicates based on your example data. To get the result you are looking for I simply apply a `DISTINCT` across the data set; however if the values of the tags vary you will still get multiple rows per specific date and time.

Example for minute-level granularity:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date_Time, Tag1_Value, Tag2_Value, Tag3_Value, Tag4_Value
  FROM (SELECT DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, Date_Time), 0) AS Date_Time
             , Tag1_Value, Tag2_Value, Tag3_Value, Tag4_Value
         FROM ProDataTable
        WHERE Date_Time BETWEEN '2017-11-17 19:05' AND '2017-11-21 19:23') AS a
GROUP BY Date_Time, Tag1_Value, Tag2_Value, Tag3_Value, Tag4_Value
ORDER BY Date_Time
```

Comment: Thanks for replay Mr.Brownstone. Seems looks this query looks work for 1 Min . but then i tried for 1hour .                                                    
  `

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT Date_Time, Tag1_Value, Tag2_Value, Tag3_Value, Tag4_Value FROM (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 1, Date_Time), 0) AS Date_Time , Tag1_Value, Tag2_Value, Tag3_Value, Tag4_Value FROM ProDataTable WHERE Date_Time BETWEEN '2017-11-17 19:05' AND '2017-11-21 19:23') AS a GROUP BY Date_Time, Tag1_Value, Tag2_Value, Tag3_Value, Tag4_Value ORDER BY Date_Time`

Comment: and for 1 hour i am not getting correct result--------------------------------------                                                       ` 2017-11-17 19:00:00.000 10 111.1 112 123.56 --------------------
2017-11-17 20:00:00.000 0 0 0 0----------------------------------
2017-11-17 21:00:00.000 0 0 0 0----------------------------------
2017-11-17 22:00:00.000 0 0 0 0----------------------------------
2017-11-19 09:00:00.000 111.111 222.222 333.333 444.444------
2017-11-19 09:00:00.000 11.11 147.55 587.25 0---------------
2017-11-19 09:00:00.000 111.111 222.222 333.333 0---------------

Comment: and Last question For this query , How i can use for 5 min or 5 Sec